# Don't we need another close reason?

Tags: feature-request, questions, close-reasons

I'm sometimes encountering questions that are *completely not about programming*, that shouldn't belong to this site at all. ([Example of such question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34456702/4354477)).

So, one should probably vote down and then vote to close. But there are not enough options for close votes.

Probably it would be better to add another one sounding like this: *"This question shouldn't belong to this site since it has nothing to do with programming"*.

Comment: Isn't there a custom off-topic, that you can type whatever you want in?

Comment: @Patrice, yes, but there's also "Questions about X are off-topic on SO since <some reason>". Why not add another close reason then?

Comment: How is a question about operator precedence in C not about programming? Just because the precedence happens to match what's used in mathematics doesn't make it off-topic.

Comment: It seemed on-topic enough for you to answer :)

Comment: @TimPost, can't I answer questions that I think are off-topic? Still, the OP needed help so why not provide it

Comment: @FOrceBru because some people might not see with a kind eye that you answer a question, get some points from it, then take an action so that no one else CAN answer.... And to your point about the existing close reasons: while true, if we start creating a separate off-topic reason for EVERYTHING, the close-vote box won't fit :P

Answer (score 7):

(I answer in general, not offering any opinion on the linked question).

The dialog with "off-topic" group of close reasons is quite long already, possibly it already has as many items as it's designed for.

Using the catch-all reason is not that difficult, because it does not actually require you to type a reason. When I use it (on other sites) and the question is so blatantly off-topic that there is no need for an explanation, I just delete "because":

[image: OT]